# In Rails 3 How to parse ISO8601 date string to get a TimeWithZone instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, timezone, iso8601

Here is my solution. Is there a more compact one?

```
> time_from_client = "2001-03-30T19:00:00-05:00"
 => "2001-03-30T19:00:00-05:00" 

> time_from_client.to_datetime
 => Fri, 30 Mar 2001 19:00:00 -0500 

> timezone_offset = time_from_client.to_datetime.offset.numerator
 => -5 

> tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[timezone_offset]
 => (GMT-05:00) America/New_York

> tz.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeZone
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, at least without getting much more clever.

To understand why you must make a distinction between a *time zone* and a *UTC offset*:

- A time zone refers to [a specific region on earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone), and may optionally have [a period of DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).
- A [UTC offset gives only the duration by which the given time is offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsets_from_UTC).

Consider mapping from zone to offset: You must also know the time in question, as well as the zone, in order to decide whether to apply the standard or daylight offset.

Going the other way is much harder. Once again just having the offset isn't enough, because we don't know whether that offset refers to standard or daylight time. But this time we have a chicken/egg problem: Even if we have the time as well, we need to know the zone in order to see if that time was standard or daylight time. But, we don't have the zone.

---

Here's a worked example from yours, you're using `Fri, 30 Mar 2001 19:00:00`, which happens to be standard time (EST), so at first pass it looks good:

```
> time_from_client = "2001-03-30T19:00:00-05:00"
 => "2001-03-30T19:00:00-05:00" 


> time_from_client.to_datetime
 => Fri, 30 Mar 2001 19:00:00 -0500 

> timezone_offset = time_from_client.to_datetime.offset.numerator
 => -5 

> tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[timezone_offset]
 => (GMT-05:00) America/New_York
```

We have `America/New_York`.

---

But see what happens if we jump to summer time, let's say, `30 Jun 2001 19:00:00`. The offset component of your `time_from_client` will now be `-04:00`, which is the daylight time offset for New York (EDT).

```
> time_from_client = "2001-03-30T19:00:00-4:00"
 => "2001-06-30T19:00:00-05:00" 


> time_from_client.to_datetime
 => Fri, 30 Jun 2001 19:00:00 -0400
```

Disclaimer: The next step doesn't actually work, because `numerator` will round down `4/24` to `1/6`, and you'll get an incorrect `timezone_offset` of `1`. As such I've tweaked your implementation and used `utc_offset`.

```
> timezone_offset = time_from_client.to_datetime.utc_offset
 => -14400

> tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[timezone_offset]
 => (GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
```

The problem can now be seen, instead of getting `America/New_York` we get `Atlantic Time (Canada)`. The latter is *one of* the zone names for the standard offset `-04:00`, because the [implementation of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[]`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-5B-5D) can only find using the standard `utc_offset`, and isn't aware of daylight.

If you follow this to its conclusion you end up with the following counter-intuitive `parse`:

```
> tz.parse "2001-06-30T19:00:00-04:00"
 => Sat, 30 Jun 2001 20:00:00 ADT -03:00
```

What I assume happens here is `TimeWithZone` sees this is June, and so adjusts to the Atlantic Daylight offset, `-03:00`.

---

It's worth noting that without even if you could account for daylight, and obtain the *standard* offset to pass to `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[]`, you'd still not have the correct zone, because the offset to zone mapping isn't one-to-one.

As demonstrated here:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select { |z| z.utc_offset == -14400 }
=> [(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada), (GMT-04:00) Georgetown, (GMT-04:00) La Paz, (GMT-04:00) Santiago]
```

This is my reason for thinking this isn't possible, unless you also happen to have location information for to the original ISO 8601 string.

Incidentally, if you pursue this approach I recommend the [tzwhere](https://github.com/mattbornski/tzwhere) Node.js library, which can uses zone geometry do do location to zone look ups.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer! It ought to be the accepted one, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) for `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`.  Short answer: use `Time.parse(time_string).in_time_zone`:

```
[9] pry(main)> Time.parse("2001-03-30T19:00:00-05:00")
=> 2001-03-30 19:00:00 -0500
[10] pry(main)> Time.parse("2001-03-30T19:00:00-05:00").class
=> Time
[11] pry(main)> Time.parse("2001-03-30T19:00:00-05:00").in_time_zone
=> Sat, 31 Mar 2001 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
[12] pry(main)> Time.parse("2001-03-30T19:00:00-05:00").in_time_zone.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

If you want it in another time zone:

```
[13] pry(main)> Time.parse("2001-03-30T19:00:00-05:00").in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles")
=> Fri, 30 Mar 2001 16:00:00 PST -08:00
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the answer. The time zone I want the TimeWithZone instance to be in IS  already contained in the iso8601 string I get from the client. Your solution will work when the client pass the time zone as another params. Note that with the first parse you have already lost the time zone information.